# Angularjs: how to handle parameter in url with routing

Tags: angularjs, parameters, routes

My URL scheme is as follows:

```
/drive/Fertilisation?open=potasse
```

I get to a page as follows:

```
<a ng-click="openPageUrl('/drive/Fertilisation?open=potasse')">open corn page</a>
```

In the controller, openPageUrl is as follows:

```
$scope.openPageUrl = function (url) {
    closePopover();
    console.log("Open page url "+url);
    $location.url(url);
};
```

Still in the controller, the route is handled, the controller handle $routeParam like this:

```
// Potential popup to open
$scope.openPopupOnLoad = $routeParams.open;
console.log("$scope.openPopupOnLoad = "+$scope.openPopupOnLoad +"; $routeParams.open = "+ $routeParams.open);
```

But it sounds like the controller loose the param, logs are as follows:

```
[Log] Open page url /drive/Fertilisation?open=potasse (kws.corn.app.js.html, line 8581)
[Log] Open page url /drive/Fertilisation (kws.corn.app.js.html, line 8581)
[Log] App controller: boots up Tue Jul 29 2014 22:54:42 GMT+0200 (CEST)
[Log] $scope.openPopupOnLoad = undefined; $routeParams.open = undefined (kws.corn.app.js.html, line 607)
[Log] App controller: already executed, won't do it again except routes (kws.corn.app.js.html, line 610)
[Log] App controller: boots up done Tue Jul 29 2014 22:54:42 GMT+0200 (CEST) (kws.corn.app.js.html, line 632)
```

How would you handle the param?

Comment: Just for any whom come across this and base the structure of their own code on the solution, be careful to sanitise the url param to only specific files that are MEANT to be accessed. Otherwise since your application will often have high OS privileges, you may get LFI or RFI vulnerabilities. 

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Local_File_Inclusion

Answer (score 1):

You can set the params in the app's route config section:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/route1/:param", {
      template: "<div>Route #1</div><div>Route param: {{param}}</div>",
      controller: "Ctrl"
    })
    .when("/route2/:param", {
      template: "<div>Route #2 </div><div>Route param: {{param}}</div>",
      controller: "Ctrl"
    });
});
```

Then refer to them in links:

```
<a href="#/route1/param">Route 1</a>
<a href="#/route2/potasse">Route 2</a>
```

Access them from the controller:

```
app.controller("Ctrl", function($scope, $routeParams) {
  $scope.param = $routeParams.param;
});
```

See [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/L4YvGurEyqTxLySjyMXw?p=preview)